# Auto Multi Threading in JavaFX?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, javafx-8

My question is, have I in some way achieved multi threading in my program because in my program, in my Controller Class which contains 2 images, when an image is clicked the control should run to paraopen or paraopen2 (depending on which image is clicked) but what really happens  is both the methods paraopen and paraopen2 execute simultaneously after clicking on both of the images one after the other. What i think should have happened is if paraopen was called(by clicking on its respective image) the control should have gone to paraopen and after finishing paraopen should have come to initialize and then to paraopen2 (by clicking on its repsective image). The methods(initialize, paraopen and paraopen2) run as if running in three different threads, which i originally wanted (sure there's a lot of repetitive code, but it works).

Can someone please help me understand how both functions paraopen and paraopen2 are working simultaneously. The player Class is my main class, and the controller class contains the code i wish to understand.

Thanks in Advance.

This is my player class(main class)

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class player extends Application {
public static void main(String args[]) {
        Application.launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader (getClass().getResource("thread1.fxml"));
    AnchorPane root = loader.load();
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root,800,600));
    stage.show();

}
}
```

This is my new Controller Class

```
package application;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.util.Duration;


public class Controller implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    ImageView player1;
    @FXML
    ImageView playero1;
    @FXML
    ImageView player2;
    @FXML
    ImageView playero2;

    TranslateTransition transition = new TranslateTransition();
    TranslateTransition transition1 = new TranslateTransition();
    TranslateTransition transition2 = new TranslateTransition();
    TranslateTransition transition2_ = new TranslateTransition();
    TranslateTransition transition3 = new TranslateTransition();
    TranslateTransition transition3_ = new TranslateTransition();
    TranslateTransition transition4 = new TranslateTransition();
    TranslateTransition transition4_ = new TranslateTransition();
    private double startDragX;
    double x = 20;
    double x1 = 120;
    double y,y1;
    int flag1 = 0;
    int flag2 = 0;

@Override
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {

    playero1.setVisible(false);
    playero2.setVisible(false);
    player1.setManaged(false);
    player1.setTranslateX(x);
     player1.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
         playero1.setTranslateX(player1.getTranslateX());
         y = player1.getTranslateY();
         playero1.setTranslateY(player1.getTranslateY());
         player1.setVisible(false);
         transition1.pause();
         playero1.setVisible(true);
         paraopen();
     });



    //This code makes the player move downwards continuously 
    transition1.setDuration(Duration.seconds(15));
    transition1.setNode(player1);
    transition1.setToY(800);
    transition1.play();

    player2.setManaged(false);
    player2.setTranslateX(120);
     player2.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
         playero2.setTranslateX(player2.getTranslateX());
         y1 = player2.getTranslateY();
         playero2.setTranslateY(player2.getTranslateY());
         player2.setVisible(false);
         transition2.pause();
         playero2.setVisible(true);
         paraopen2();
     });



    //This code makes the player move downwards continuously 
    transition2.setDuration(Duration.seconds(15));
    transition2.setNode(player2);
    transition2.setToY(800);
    transition2.play();


}
public void paraopen() {
    playero1.setManaged(false);


     playero1.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
         startDragX = e.getSceneX();
         flag1 = 1;
     });

     playero1.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {

         if(flag1 ==1) {
         double X = e.getSceneX();
          if(X - startDragX > 0) {
              x = x + 10;
              playero1.setTranslateX(x);
              flag1 = 0;
          }
         else if (X - startDragX  < 0) {
              x = x - 10;
              playero1.setTranslateX(x);
              flag1 = 0;
         }
         }
     });

    //This code makes the player move downwards continuously 
    transition.setDuration(Duration.seconds(19));
    transition.setNode(playero1);
    transition.setToY(800);
    transition.play();
}

public void paraopen2() {
    playero2.setManaged(false);


     playero2.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
         startDragX = e.getSceneX();
         flag2 = 1;
     });

     playero2.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {

         if(flag2 ==1) {
         double X = e.getSceneX();
          if(X - startDragX > 0) {
              x1 = x1 + 10;
              playero2.setTranslateX(x1);
              flag2 = 0;
          }
         else if (X - startDragX  < 0) {
              x1 = x1 - 10;
              playero2.setTranslateX(x1);
              flag2 = 0;
         }
         }
     });

    //This code makes the player move downwards continuously 
    double r = ((800-y1)*19)/(800-y);
    transition2_.setDuration(Duration.seconds(r));
    transition2_.setNode(playero2);
    transition2_.setToY(800);
    transition2_.play();
}

}
```

This is my FXML file

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane  maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.Controller">
   <children>
      <ImageView fx:id="player1" fitHeight="42.0" fitWidth="98.0" layoutX="47.0" layoutY="27.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@freefall.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
        <ImageView fx:id="playero1" fitHeight="80" fitWidth="80" layoutX="47.0" layoutY="27.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@freefallp.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
        <ImageView fx:id="player2" fitHeight="42.0" fitWidth="98.0" layoutX="47.0" layoutY="27.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@freefall.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
        <ImageView fx:id="playero2" fitHeight="80" fitWidth="80" layoutX="47.0" layoutY="27.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@freefallp.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>

   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: *"what i want to do is make multiple threads of single images"* - You don't need multiple threads, you probably only need one. You might like to have a look at [Concurrency in JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm) as a starting point

Comment: Thanks I will look into concurrency.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I could not quite understand the use of tasks from the oracle documentation and could not find suitable resources on concurrency, It would really help me a lot if you could show me how to use multiple tasks simultaneously. Can you just give me an example of how you would implement two image view's in a scene both having the functionality in the Controller Class. I tried using tasks but somehow i can't make my tasks run simultaneously. Thank you

Comment: You only need one

Comment: Why do you think you need any threads at all here? What are you doing that need threads?

Comment: What i want to do is run two image views simultaneously in my scene, which have the same functionality. Can you tell me how the three methods initialize(), paraopen() and paraopen2() are running simultaneously, in my Controller Class. As far as i know methods work on stacks. Then how are they working simultaneously. Thanks